# Ridiculous accounts packages resource usage

Tags: node.js, meteor

I've minimized my app down to just using the accounts-ui and accounts-steam packages (and a bunch of client packages). Here is the entirity of the client subscription log:

[image]

Trying to support only a few hundred clients at once, and the subscriptions take AGES to go through. It's about half an hour until the accounts-ui buttons even appear. I'm on a pretty hefty DigitalOcean instance with 2 cpus and they are both maxed out all the time. Only thing running is the bundled Meteor app. 686mb of memory usage as well.

So, seriously, i've had to phase my entire app off of Meteor into other solutions... It's beginning to seem like Meteor is good for client stuff but too huge of a resource hog for anything server intensive.

How the heck do I fix this?

Comment: I've experienced this before with my Meteor app, over 300 clients it started to explode. It might be more helpful if you gave a bit of more info, are you on oplog? also where is your db hosted (latency in between your DO server and your mongodb)? How long did the login above take? I aimed at the latency and that helped the most (5s down to 100ms) though 100ms is still a long time

Comment: @Akshat Oplog enabled. DigitalOcean on the same host as the MongoHQ elastic (paid) instance I'm using for DB. Latancy is very little. Login above still hasn't completed (45 minutes later).

Comment: I am not sure what am I supposed to see from the screenshot? What is the version of Meteor? What is the CPU/MEM characteristics of your server? How big is your current database with users and access tokens? How many servers do you have?

Comment: @imslavko Latest meteor. 2 cpus. about 5k users. One server in this instance because all it is is a login button.

Comment: @ChristianStewart 5k users is quite large have you considered horizontal scaling instead? Also are your subscriptions odd or different in any way (special queries, custom publishes (using this.ready/this.added). Also your screenshot shows all of it happening in the same minute, is it from a fresh reboot?

Comment: @Akshat Those are all sent right as the page loads up. I've tried scaling before but it didn't really solve the issue - if one host can only take ~200 users for JUST a login button then I think Meteor is absolutely unusable for larger projects.

Comment: @ChristianStewart This is quite scary to me I have not experienced 5k users it would be nice to know more about your app is it anywhere live? With my issue of 300 users I did the db latency and moved up from aws from a micro to a m3 large which fixed it, but I've not gone beyond 400 users

Comment: @Akshat http://alpha.d2modd.in/ - I had to move all app logic from Meteor to a custom built from the ground up .net server. Meteor used to run everything. Now it runs nothing, and can barely handle the signins... I'm now moving to angular and bare express server side for the login.

Comment: @ChristianStewart Are you able to share your app's source code and/or anonymized database? We'd like to debug this but it's difficult without more information.

Comment: @Emily Sure, I could make a reproduction repo. Basically it's just `accounts-steam` (maybe that's the issue?) and accounts-ui-bootstrap-3 and `authorization`. Do you need a repro for that? (though most of the lag comes from the resume operation)